# Update multi items of array in MongoDB using C# Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core

I have a document like this sample:

```
    [
{ 
"_id" : "id1",     
"items" : [
    {
        "_id" : "f449dc0b-3d1b-4a59-b622-6a42ce10b147",
        "token" : "aaa",  
        "isExpired" : false, 
        "expiredAt" : ISODate("")
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "3d1497d7-f74c-4d88-b15c-bf2f9c736374", 
        "token" : "bbb",  
        "isExpired" : false, 
        "expiredAt" : ISODate("")
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "6e827e2a-5a25-4343-b646-885816bb8cc4", 
        "token" : "ccc",  
        "isExpired" : false, 
        "expiredAt" : ISODate("")
    }]
},
...,
...
]
```

If I have the `_id` of the document and a `token` of the items, How can I expire **every item except given token**?

For example, if the document id is `"id1"` and the token is `"aaa"`, I want the `"bbb"` and `"ccc"` tokens to expire.

I prefer the operation to be done with a **single query** and without replacing the entire document or array.

My code is something like this, but only one item expires each time:

```
var filter = Builders<Document>.Filter
.And(
    Builders<Document>.Filter.Eq(d => d.Id, "id1"), 
    Builders<Document>.Filter.ElemMatch(d => d.items, item => item.token != "aaa"));

var update = Builders<Document>.Update
            .Set(x => x.items[-1].isExpired, true)
            .Set(x => x.items[-1].expiredAt, DateTime.UtcNow);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to start with I'm going to insert the sample record you have give but have the expiredAts all to null.

```js
> db.test.insert({
    "_id" : "id1",
    "items" : [
        {
            "_id" : "f449dc0b-3d1b-4a59-b622-6a42ce10b147",
            "token" : "aaa",
            "isExpired" : false,
            "expiredAt" : null
        },
        {
            "_id" : "3d1497d7-f74c-4d88-b15c-bf2f9c736374",
            "token" : "bbb",
            "isExpired" : false,
            "expiredAt" : null
        },
        {
            "_id" : "6e827e2a-5a25-4343-b646-885816bb8cc4",
            "token" : "ccc",
            "isExpired" : false,
            "expiredAt" : null
        }]
    })
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

Now for the C# we need to take advantage of the array filters as a normal find can either update one item in an array (with the positional [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)) or update all items in an array (with the all positional operator [$[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/)).

```cs
var client = new MongoClient();

var db = client.GetDatabase("test");
var collection = db.GetCollection<Document>("test");


var filter = Builders<Document>.Filter.Eq(d => d.Id, "id1");

var update = Builders<Document>.Update
    .Set("items.$[i].isExpired", true)
    .Set("items.$[i].expiredAt", DateTime.UtcNow);

var arrayFilterDefinitions = new ArrayFilterDefinition[]
{
    new BsonDocumentArrayFilterDefinition<Item>(BsonDocument.Parse(@"{ ""i.token"" : { $ne: ""aaa"" } }"))
};
await collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update, new UpdateOptions{ArrayFilters = arrayFilterDefinitions});
```

Executing the above will just update the items in the array where the token is not "aaa".

More information can be found on the MongoDB documentation - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#identifier

```js
> db.test.findOne()
{
        "_id" : "id1",
        "items" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "f449dc0b-3d1b-4a59-b622-6a42ce10b147",
                        "token" : "aaa",
                        "isExpired" : false,
                        "expiredAt" : null
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "3d1497d7-f74c-4d88-b15c-bf2f9c736374",
                        "token" : "bbb",
                        "isExpired" : true,
                        "expiredAt" : ISODate("2020-08-13T15:57:00.582Z")
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "6e827e2a-5a25-4343-b646-885816bb8cc4",
                        "token" : "ccc",
                        "isExpired" : true,
                        "expiredAt" : ISODate("2020-08-13T15:57:00.582Z")
                }
        ]
}
```